# What port to forward on Ubuntu Server 22.04.1 and apache2 webserver

Tags: networking, server, apache2, webserver

I'm extremely new to servers and ubuntu. But I have tried to make a webserver at home, on an laptop, using Ubuntu Server 22.04.1.

I want to portforward, so I can firstly remote into it from a different aswell as connect to wendomains that I have set up with Apache2 and some test html.

How do I figure out what port i'm supposed to forward?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You are correct, I'm so sorry. I'll correct it now!

Comment: You will want to first confirm with your ISP that they allow incoming traffic on the standard ports used by browsers (80 and 443) as well as SSH (22). If your ISP allows connections from the Internet to your home machine, then you can configure port forwarding in the router to those three.

Comment: Okay, I will try to contact my ISP and check with them. Thanks!